Can I Apply the "OHS DB19C" Patch to an Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) Configured in Native Mode?
I need to address some security vulnerabilities in my Oracle HTTP Server (OHS), which is configured in native mode (i.e., integrated with WebLogic Server and not directly interacting with a database). The patch I intend to apply is named "OHS DB19C", and it supports the same version of OHS that I have installed (12.2.1.4).
Since the patch seems to be targeted at setups involving a database client, I am unsure if it can be applied to my native-only OHS configuration. Has anyone applied a similar patch in a native OHS setup? Will applying this patch have any impact, or are there compatibility considerations I should be aware of?
